# An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, nokogiri, rubber

When I run cap deploy, it stops by saying this:

```
    ubuntu@web01b:~$ sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1 for inspection.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you resolved the requirements first?

```
libxml2
libxml2-dev
libxslt
libxslt-dev
```

http://nokogiri.org